# Return button text after toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, reactjs, state

I have the following React component:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

module.exports = {
    trigger: '.form-trigger',
    form: '.financial-form',
    init: function() {
        $(this.trigger).click(this.toggleForm.bind(this));
    },
    toggleForm: function(e) {
        // define currentTarget
        var currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget);
        // define current Text
        var currentText = currentTarget.html();
        // Prevent anchor click default
        e.preventDefault();
        // Remove any active classes
        currentTarget.next(form).slideToggle("fast");
        // console.log(currentText);
        if ($(this.form).is(":visible")){
            // $(element).is(":visible")
            currentTarget.html("Close Form");
        } else {
            currentTarget.html(currentText);
        }
    }
};
```

There are multiple 'triggers' on the page which open up their adjacent forms. Inside the toggleForm function, the 'if' statement determines the text of the button.  I store the buttons current Text so that if the form is open, I can change to "Close Form" or else return the button to its original text.  However the currentText variable is storing the "Close Form" Text as it becomes the currentTarget.  How can I make sure the button's text returns to its original state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the original text in jQuery's `data()`

```
var $ = require('jquery');

module.exports = {
    trigger : '.form-trigger',
    form    : '.financial-form',
    init    : function() {
        $(this.trigger).click(this.toggleForm.bind(this));
    },
    toggleForm: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget),
            flag          = $(this.form).data('flag');

        currentTarget.next(form).slideToggle("fast");

        if ( !currentTarget.data('text') ) {
            currentTarget.data('text', currentTarget.text());
        }

        currentTarget.text(flag ? currentTarget.data('text') : "Close Form");
        $(this.form).data('flag', !flag);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this does not work.  Even when the form is closed the button's text remains "Close Form"

Comment: You're sure the logic is sound? Especially noting that `is(':visible')` won't work on animated methods, as the element would always be visible while sliding etc. but it's not really clear what the form is, why you use `currentTarget` instead of `this` and `this.form` etc ?

Comment: adeneo, thanks for the helpful tips.  If I don't use currentTarget, then other hidden forms on the page open?

Comment: That works great, but I don't understand why.  Any chance you could explain it to me a bit?

Comment: It uses a flag to toggle the text instead of `is(':visible')`. As I noted above, the element is visible while being toggle, so when the `if` condition is hit, the element is always visible, because it's being animated.